# Where do I get the google artifact from?

Tags: guava

So I'm trying to build guava from source with maven2 but it seems to need the 'google' artifact as parent. Where is the upstream website of this artifact? (yes, I need the source, not just the artifact).

Answer (score 0):

The guava-parent artifact is in the main source repo for guava under maven/pom.xml

Just do "mvn -N install" from the maven directory and you'll have it in your local repo.  Having said that, it should have automatically picked it up - I'll check out a fresh workspace with an empty local repository and make sure the main guava project will automatically find the parent pom.

Comment: Hi,

I've not asked for guava-parent but for the artifactId "google":

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google</groupId>
    <artifactId>google</artifactId>
    <version>5</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava-parent</artifactId>

And I'm specifically asking for the source because I can't use auto-download feature of mvn as I want to package guava for a distro and certainly need all deps as packages in the same repo.

Thanks,
red